# Angular 4 - Call a function while clicking on overlay label of jsplumb

Tags: angular, jsplumb

I'm using jsplumb to connect elements in angular 4 and trying to show modal with dynamic content while clicking on label of jsplumb.

Below is the code

*component.ts*

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   jsPlumb.ready(function () {
      var common = {
        connector: ["Flowchart"],
        anchor: ["Left", "Right"],
        endpoint: "Dot"
      };    
      jsPlumb.connect({
        source: "item_left",
        target: "item_right",
        paintStyle: { stroke: "lightgray", strokeWidth: 3 },
        endpointStyle: { fillStyle: "lightgray", outlineStroke: "gray" },
        overlays: [
          ["Arrow", { width: 24, length: 24, location: 0.80 }],
          ["Label", {
            label: "Process", id: "label", cssClass: "aLabel",
            events: {
              click: function (labelOverlay, originalEvent) {
                this.onJobSelect("jobId");
              }    
            }    
          }]    
        ]
      }, common);
   })
}

onJobSelect(jobId) {
//code...
}
```

Here onJobSelect() function is not recognized and values of variables inside click event are not getting resolved in view. Any suggestions for resolving this issue??

Comment: Use arrow functions and you will be closer to your solution

Comment: Still can't change the values of  angular variables inside jsPlumb.connect() and firing undefined error

Answer (score 0):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   let self = this;
   jsPlumb.ready(function () {
      var common = {
        connector: ["Flowchart"],
        anchor: ["Left", "Right"],
        endpoint: "Dot"
      };    
      jsPlumb.connect({
        source: "item_left",
        target: "item_right",
        paintStyle: { stroke: "lightgray", strokeWidth: 3 },
        endpointStyle: { fillStyle: "lightgray", outlineStroke: "gray" },
        overlays: [
          ["Arrow", { width: 24, length: 24, location: 0.80 }],
          ["Label", {
            label: "Process", id: "label", cssClass: "aLabel",
            events: {
              click: function (labelOverlay, originalEvent) {
                self.onJobSelect("jobId");
              }    
            }    
          }]    
        ]
      }, common);
   })
}

onJobSelect(jobId) {
//code...
}
```

We have scope issue, That's the reason your not able to call onJobSelect function.

So refere my code, The code is working properly.

Thanks